# non-type template argument does not refer to any declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                               
#include <string>                                                                                                                 

using namespace std;                                                                                                              

template <typename T,                                                                                                             
          typename T::type N,                                                                                                     
          typename T::strata& X>                                                                                                  
struct SomeClass{};                                                                                                               

struct S1                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                 
  typedef int type;                                                                                                               
  typedef string strata;                                                                                                          
};                                                                                                                                

int main () {                                                                                                                     
  SomeClass<S1, 3, string("erg")> x;                                                                                              
}
```

fails with message:

> ```
>  g++ templ.cc -o templ -std=c++14                                                                                   
>  templ.cc:18:20: error: non-type template argument does not refer to any declaration                                               
>    SomeClass<S1, 3, string("erg")> x;                                                                                              
>                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                  
>  templ.cc:8:24: note: template parameter is declared here                                                                          
>            typename T::strata& X>
> ```

Why it works for the int but not for string?
Why it says the string is non-type argument?

Comment: because it's not a type. And non-type arguments are limited to primitives (actually, integrals and pointers)

Comment: @PasserBy Reference to class type, as used here, is also allowed.

Comment: And... I didn't see that reference :)

Comment: this code smells fishy as hell. What are you ideally looking to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A template argument that is a value rather than a type or template is simply called a "non-type template argument".

This fails because of the reference.  You would get a similar error on the `3` if you had `typename T::type& N`.

To quote [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters),

> The following limitations apply when instantiating templates that have non-type template parameters:
>
> - For lvalue reference parameters, the argument provided at instantiation cannot be a temporary, an unnamed lvalue, or a named lvalue with no linkage (in other words, the argument must have linkage).

So your temporary is invalid.  But you could do:

```
std::string erg("erg");
int main () {                                                                                                                     
  SomeClass<S1, 3, erg> x;                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: why it complains that "there is no linkage" if I put string inside main() ?

Comment: Because a variable with automatic storage duration has no linkage.